# Suma acumulativa con expresion en oracle

Tags: oracle

Estoy tratando de hacer una suma acumulativa con la siguiente query:

```
SELECT to_char(INVC_DT, 'MON-YYYY') AS MONTH 
       ,SUM(INVC_AMT)
       /*, aqui necesito una tercera columna con la suma cumulativa de la segunda columna*/
FROM T_INVC_INFO I INNER JOIN T_TASK_INFO T ON I.TASK_ID = T.TASK_ID
WHERE T.CNTRCT_ID = #session.user.cntrct_id#
GROUP BY to_char(INVC_DT, 'MON-YYYY')
ORDER BY MONTH DESC
```

Comment: Hola, no comprendo lo de la tercer columna con suma acumulativa, puedes darme una explicación mas en detalle

Comment: Suponiendo que tengo dos meses: `ENE-2018` y `FEB-2018` con valores respectivamente de: `200` y `300`, entonces la tercera columna tendria que tener valores de: `200` y `500`, o sea la suma cumulativa de la segunda columna.

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta, ojala te sirva.

Comment: la tercera columna tendria que ser MAR-2018 y la cuarta  ABR-2018, en donde la columna MAR-2018 tiene valor de 200 y la columna ABR-2018 tiene valor de 500, eso? luego seguiria MAY-2018 von calor de 200 y luego JUN-2018 con valor de 700, eso?

Comment: No hay cuarta columna, me refiero a que los valores de la primera fila serian: ENE-2018, 200, 200.  La segunda fila seria: FEB-2018, 300, 500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final lo resolvi con esta query con la ayuda de StackOverflow en Ingles:

```
SELECT to_char(INVC_DT, 'MON-YYYY') AS MONTH,
       SUM(INVC_AMT) AS SUM_MONTH,
       SUM(SUM(INVC_AMT)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(INVC_DT)) AS CUMULATIVE_SUM
FROM T_INVC_INFO I INNER JOIN T_TASK_INFO T ON I.TASK_ID = T.TASK_ID
WHERE T.CNTRCT_ID = #session.user.cntrct_id#        
GROUP BY to_char(INVC_DT, 'MON-YYYY')
ORDER BY MIN(INVC_DT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentarlo de esta forma:

```
        set serveroutput on;
        DECLARE
            cursor cCOnsulta is select 'fecha1' fecha, 20 valor from dual union select 'fecha2' fecha, 30 valor from dual union select 'fecha3' fecha, 40 valor from dual;
          registro cCOnsulta%ROWTYPE;
          acumulador number := 0;
        BEGIN
        open cCOnsulta;
        LOOP 
           FETCH cCOnsulta into registro; 
              EXIT WHEN cCOnsulta%notfound; 
                    acumulador := acumulador + registro.valor;
                    //aqui podrias insertar los valores en una tabla temporal o imprimirlos
                      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(registro.fecha||'  '||registro.valor||'  '||acumulador);
              END LOOP;
        close cCOnsulta;
        END;
```

Espero te sirva!